# Simple In App Purchase App Android

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to make a simple app in android dev eclipse with a simple in app purchase item like 50 coins for 0.50p in android because there are absolutely no tutorials out there and the android in app billing example isn't exactly helpful.

Comment: In-app billing is such a pain to try to wrap ones head around. They should really add some sort of abstraction layer to it, where we only need to add the ID (from Android Market) as a parameter to something for basic purchases, and also maybe a callback url or similar. :-)

Comment: true or a simple tutorial which shows you how to do a basic thing which then you can use to expand on

Comment: you ll have to use the sample available and add the correspinding aidl file.Your product must be unmanaged on android market.And just try to understand the flow.And revert back if you have any other problems

Comment: What is wrong with the "in app billing" example code ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The current version of Android In App Purchase is V3

http://blog.blundellapps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/

---

My blog post is titled Simple In App Purchase v2, so that might help:

http://blog.blundellapps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/

I've also recently written an overview with a flowchart to try and explain InApp Purchase (not so simple):

http://blog.blundellapps.com/overview-of-android-in-app-billing-flowchart/ (v2)

[image]

Comment: Thought i'd add your updated v3 tutorial, its extremely helpful http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment-v3/ cheers Blundell

Comment: **Attention!  Check out my reply**   (`below`)   on `Aug 7 '13`

Comment: plus for that complicated and very clever block scheme

Answer (score 10):

Does [this library (AndroidBillingLibrary)](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary) solve your problem?

Comment: Also http://mcondev.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/integrate-in-app-billing-just-3-lines-of-code-in-your-app/

Answer (score 4):

***Attention!***

**Here is answer for IAB v2**

And **you**, most likely, **looking for v3** (which is **much simpler**)

Don't get in this trap, as I did...

Google I/O 2013 - In-App Billing Version 3 -  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgcJPIRpfSk

Answer (score 0):

You can check example with library for inn app billing. 
[Example](https://github.com/Ucdemir/Ucdemir-Inn_App_Purchase_v2)